# Why AWS ELB EC2 instance gets reinitiated after being stopped by a scheduler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to do cost optimization to reduce the cost of using AWS resources by stopping EC2 and RDS instance when they are not in use.

I managed to create a scheduler using AWS CloudFormation service, and the instances are stopping according to the scheduler configurations but the problem is that after the instance gets stopped, AWS initiate another one.

Please advice if there is a way to control this behavior or change it.

Regards.

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Marcin , I was trying many approaches to get it to work the way 
 I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank @**Marcin** and @**Jatin** for their answers.

> Notes:

- Detaching EC2 instance without setting the Desired capacity and
  Minimum capacity to 0 won't help because ASG will launch a new
  instance.
- If you set Desired capacity and Minimum capacity to 0 instance will
  get terminated automatically.
- Detaching EC2 and setting Desired capacity and Minimum capacity to 0 (if allowed)
  will lead to a sever health status in your ELB Environment and you
  won't be able to restart your APP or rebuild the environment until
  you set the Desired capacity and Minimum capacity to 1 and do the
  process over again.
- You can't put EC2 on standby if Desired capacity and Minimum capacity
  are set to 0.

> My approach to solving the problem:

1. Set Desired capacity to 1 and Minimum capacity to 0 in the [Auto
   Scaling group][1] details.
2. Scroll down to the `Advanced configurations` and add `Terminate` to the
   `Suspended processes`.
3. Go to `Automatic Scaling` tab of the Auto Scaling group, choose first
   policy on the left then click `edit` from the `Actions` menu. In the
   `Take the action` field, choose `set to` instead of `remove` then click update.
4. Go to your EC2 instance the you need to schedule and and add the
   scheduler `tag` to it.

The Previous approach will help you schedule the [stop & start] of ELB EC2 instance, if your project runs on one instance and you need to do cost optimization.
If you are using more than one EC2 instance, you need to adjust the previous configurations.

Answer (score 2):

You **can't stop** instances in Elastic Beanstalk (EB) by just stopping, as they run in [AutoScaling Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html). So once you stop the instance, ASG will launch a replacement, which is expected.

The proper way to stop the instances in auto-scaling group is to [detach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/detach-instance-asg.html) them first, or best to set [min and desired capacity to 0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-capacity-limits.html). The last option will terminate the instances, but this is the easiest strategy to reduce cost of running instances in ASG when not needed.

But since you are terminating instances, you may as well terminate entire EB environment, and launch new one when needed. This should be easy if you do it using CloudFormation.

Comment: Be careful... you probably don't want the database to be terminated if it was created by Elastic Beanstalk. I agree that setting the Auto Scaling Group to `Desired Capacity = 0` is a good way of doing it, but might not be compatible with the scheduler you deployed. You'll also need a way to increase the Desired Capacity again when you want it to continue working. This technique will _not_ stop/start the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Marcin's answer is all you need, but if you are considering `to stop an instance in ASG` then maybe this can help you :-

1. **Standby State** :- ASG wont perform health checks on instances in the standby state.
2. **Detach it** :- once instances are detached, manage them independently, decrement the desired capacity of ASG by number if instances that being detached, otherwise asg will launch new instances to replace the ones that we detached.
3. **Stop the health check process** :- WHen asg marks instances unhealthy, it is terminated and launches a new once. if you don't want instances to be replaced,, suspend health check process for the entire ASG